# accordian with JQuery click, slideUp and slideDown

Tags: jquery

I want to disply 3 divs on a  page (accordian with JQuery click, slideUp and slideDown functions)

But I want one of the divs to be "open" when page loads.

Here is my code,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.title').click(function() {

$('.title').removeClass('on');

$('.content').slideUp('normal');

if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {

$(this).addClass('on');

$(this).next().slideDown('normal');
}

});

});
```

---

```
css,


.title {
padding-left:15px;
height:17px;
background: url(images/arrow-toggle.png) 0 3px no-repeat !important;
cursor:pointer;
margin-bottom:10px;
color:#104675;

}

.on {
background: url(images/arrow-toggle.png) 0 -12px no-repeat !important;
}

.content {
display:none;
background-color:#f4f2f3;
border: #CCCCCC 1px solid;
padding: 10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

--------
HTML,

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dropdownwitharrows.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/dropdownwitharrows.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="title"><h1>Header One</h1></div>
<div class="content"><p>content here..bla bla bla</p></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please read the documentation, the JQuery accordion control has an option to set the default open element

Comment: why don't you try to use http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion ...they have a built in option-collapsible ..that is exactly what you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $titles = $('.title'), $contents = $('.content');

    $titles.click(function() {
        var $acts = $titles.filter('.on').removeClass('on');
        $acts.next().finish().slideUp('normal');
        if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
            $(this).addClass('on');
            $(this).next().finish().slideDown('normal');
        }
    }).first().click();

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/39LJ4/)

Comment: But if I dont want the divs to close when I toggle other divs, any easy way to fix that?